# Why JWPlayer no sound only in iphone?

Tags: javascript, frontend, jwplayer

I have an issue with JW PLAYER and it is no sound only in iPHONE Mobile

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: "{{url('xxxx')}}"+'/'+id,
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function (data) {

        player.setup({
            "sharing": {
                "sites": ["reddit","facebook","twitter"]
            },

            autostart: true,
            mute: false,

            cast:{ },
            skin: {
                name: "six"
            },
            width:"100%",
            aspectratio: "16:9",

            playlist: [{
                tracks: data.subtitles,
                image: data.image,
                sources:data.sources
            }],
        });
    }
});

player.on('ready', function(event){
    var toggle=$('.share-button');
    sharingPlugin = jwplayer().getPlugin('sharing');
    sharingPlugin.on('open',function(){
        toggle.attr('status','1');
    });

    sharingPlugin.on('close',function(){
        toggle.attr('status','0');
    })

});

jwplayer().on('ready',function(){jwplayer().setCurrentQuality(2)});
```

Comment: Check that the video file plays correctly on the device _without_ JW player.

Comment: yes play video on iphone but no sound ...

Comment: There's your issue. Fix the video, not the player.

Comment: Is video playing initiated with a user interaction or do you just start playing the video?  Sound can only be played after an interaction from the user, like clicking on something.

Comment: i can't click on mute icon on mobile !

Answer (score 0):

Browsers require the player to be muted in order for media to autoplay on mobile. The blog post here describes this requirement in greater detail:

https://www.jwplayer.com/blog/mobile-web-autoplay/